# Make objection model return match the TS interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, knex.js, objection.js

I'm working to implement an api using express/objection js and typescript.

I took a lot of inspiration from this repo: https://github.com/HappyZombies/brackette-alpha/tree/master/server/src

As the creator did, I want to have different interfaces for a same "component" ( eg: user ).

We can see here that he create different interfaces ([here](https://github.com/HappyZombies/brackette-alpha/blob/master/server/src/interfaces/IUser.ts)) and he uses them in his services as a returned promise ([here](https://github.com/HappyZombies/brackette-alpha/blob/master/server/src/services/UserService.ts)) but there is no check that what he returned does match his interface. Eg: to match his promised interface here, he will only select the sql field that match his interface

```js
  public async findAll(): Promise<IUserMiminimum[]> {
    let users;
    try {
      users = await this.usersModel.query().column('username', 'displayName');
    } catch (err) {
      this.logger.error(err);
      throw err;
    }
    return users;
  }
```

My questions are:

- Is there a way to only select the fields you want from the model results based on the interface description ?
- Else, is there a way to check the interface match the model results ?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Objection [castTo()](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/other-methods.html#castto) might help with that

```
const users= await User.query()
  .column('username', 'displayName')
  .castTo<IUser[]>();
```

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of this function but with the interface it will simply cast it and not make it fit my interface :(